# Why is my typed data template not being applied?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I'm using Linq To Sql to fill up a listbox with Segment objects, where Segment is designer created/ORM generated class.

```
<Window x:Class="ICTemplates.Window1"
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ICTemplates"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate"> 
      <!--  <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type local:Segment"> -->
        // some stuff in here
      </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView x:Name="tvwSegments" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" MaxHeight="200"/>


// code-behind
var queryResults = from segment in tblSegments
                               where segment.id <= iTemplateSid
                               select segment;
tvwSegments.DataContext = queryResults;
```

This works.

However if I used a Typed Data Template (by replacing the x:Key with the DataType attribute on the template, the items all show up with `ICTemplates.Segment` (the ToString() return value)
The concept is that it should pick up the data template automatically if the Type matches. Can someone spot the mistake here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ze Mistake is here

```
<DataTemplate DataType="x:Type local:Segment">  <!-- doesn't work -->
```

should be

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Segment}">
```

Came home... made a toy-sample and it worked with this change. Gotta try that @ work tomorrow. Sheesh.. for want of 2 curlies..

**Update**: Found out another gotcha

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SegTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Segment}">  <!-- doesn't work -->
```

won't work. Seems like you can have it either with a Key **OR** DataType attribute. To make this typed data template work.. had to remove the Key attribute and now it works as expected. Behavior is consistent for a HierarchicalDataTemplate too.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Segment}">
```

Comment: According to the docs, x:Key overrides the implicit (auto-generated) type-dependent key. The template keeps working, but you have to declare it explicitly in the object.

Comment: I experienced the issue with the key. Thank you :)

Comment: Shame on you, Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but could it be because the context is set to an IQueryable?  If you  set the DataContext to a single instance of a Segment, do you get the same result?